# VBS with IE didn't work

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I am trying to open IE from vbs and it worked from the PC i was working from (Windows 10 x64) but when i try to open the same code on my PC (Windows 10 Pro x64(It shows 'Windows 10 Enterprise' because i've cracked the license)) I am getting everytime the same error:

Line: 9
Character: 1
Error: Authorization denied: 'CreateObject'
Error Code: 800A0046

Here's my complete code:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"
strValueName = "Version"
oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue
URL = InputBox("Please enter an URL","PrivateBrowser v"&strValue,"http://google.com")
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Toolbar = False
objIE.StatusBar = False
objIE.MenuBar = False
objIE.Navigate URL
objIE.Visible = True
```

I've searched for a while but i can't find a solution.

Comment: Please tell what line does the error points to (as message shows).

Comment: Your complete code works fine for me on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, so there are no problems in your code.

Comment: Ah ok... So is my copy of windows 10 that didn't work. Thanks.